css style platform compatibility
for people working as full stack or front-end web developers and use css a lot i want to ask you how you deal with screen sizing and make your website look the same across all platforms, this is a real problem i am currently facing since i dont know whats a better practice and need your advice: do you use multiple media queries like these @ media screen and (min-width:npx)
or do you within the code make the margins, paddings, fontsizes... shrink as screen shrinks.
i tried the first option and it worked well for me but i dont know if its a better practice, the second option was super hard since after designing the website and making it look perfect if i change one thing the whole design just breaks, so whats better should i use the first option or should i work more on skills related to second option

This is not the right place to ask questions like this. But you may start from responsive design or similar courses

oh stack overflow isnt the right place to ask web development questions?

Stack Overflow's more for specific, technical questions rather than those that are too broad, hypothetical, or opinion-based. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

I didn't make the rules, but generally opinion based questions are not allowed here. (Not my downvote btw)

You'll want to be using Breakpoints (@media queries) and dynamic sizing for margins, paddings, font sizes, etc. Using the latter option alone would be insufficient.
Run the code snippet from the examples below. Resize the browser window and notice how the content and font size changes.
Example 1: Breakpoints and fixed font-size (using px):


/* Original code from W3Schools */

.example {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}


/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .example {
    background: red;
  }
}


/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .example {
    background: green;
  }
}


/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .example {
    background: blue;
  }
}


/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .example {
    background: orange;
  }
}


/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .example {
    background: pink;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Typical Breakpoints</h2>
  <p class="example">Resize the browser window to see how the background color of this paragraph changes on different screen sizes.</p>

</body>

</html>



Example 2: Breakpoints and dynamic font-size (using vw):


/* Original code from W3Schools */

.example {
  font-size: 3vw;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}


/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .example {
    background: red;
  }
}


/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .example {
    background: green;
  }
}


/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .example {
    background: blue;
  }
}


/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .example {
    background: orange;
  }
}


/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .example {
    background: pink;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Typical Breakpoints</h2>
  <p class="example">Resize the browser window to see how the background color of this paragraph changes on different screen sizes.</p>

</body>

</html>



